# Trouble adding individual x,y vertices

Tags: python, loops, arcpy

I am trying to have the individual vertices run through vertXY equation, but am unable to get it to run correctly, any suggestions?

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_shp, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))
    partnum = 0
    for part in row[1]:
        print("Part {}:".format(partnum))
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                verticeX = ("{}".format(pnt.X))
                verticeY = ("{}".format(pnt.Y))
                print verticeX, verticeY
            else:
                print("Interior Ring:")
                for vert in pnt:
                    if vert:
                        vertXY = (verticeX*verticeY+1)-(verticeX+1*verticeY)
                        print VertXY
        partnum += 1

print 'step 1c'
```

Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\FPT.py", line 80, in <module>
for vert in pnt[1]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Line in your traceback isn't in your code. Closest line to it is in the wrong conditional block.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am new to programming so the `for vert in pnt:` loop isn't in my code and it's formatted incorrectly?

Comment: I think the [gis.se] Stack Exchange is the site to research/ask ArcPy questions on.